# Performance analysis of a HttpHandler

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, httphandler, analysis

`Visual Studio >> Debug menu >> Start performance analysis` doesn't work with a `HttpHandler` because it cannot be run by itself. The error is something like this:

getting asp.net information failed. 'http://localhost/myprojrct/VSEnterpriseHelper.axd' returned error (500 internal server error)

Also attaching to `w3wp.exe` via `profiler` only profiles CPU.

How is it possible to run performance analysis on a `HttpHandler` asp.net project (I don't use `ashx` file and there's no asp.net page, just a class which implements `IHttpHandler`)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to move your processing logic out of your `IHttpHandler` implementation and into a class that *can* be tested with Profiler. Keep your footprint for the handler as small as possible.